# mysql php statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have these statements.

```
"SELECT * FROM PLACE.country WHERE Number='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."'";<br>
"SELECT * FROM PLACE.country WHERE StreetNumber='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."'";<br>
"SELECT * FROM PLACE.country WHERE PostNumber='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."'";
```

how do i join these into a single statement?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"
    SELECT *
    FROM PLACE.country
    WHERE Number='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."'
       OR StreetNumber='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."'
       OR PostNumber='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."'
";
```

Answer (score 3):

[The SQL `AND & OR` statement](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-AND-OR.asp).

Here's an example (in SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `a`='1' AND `b`='2' AND `c`='3'
```

/neurotic

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `a`='1' OR `b`='2' OR `c`='3'
```

Comment: Keep in mind you can use AND logic or OR logic, I guess it depends on what he wants.

Comment: Though the question is highly vague, I think this is not what he wanted.

Comment: @AndreKR after reading Nermoden's I would have to agree with you.  My mind just immediately jumped to `AND`.  I should have included an example of `OR` as well.  But the link goes over `OR` too.

Answer (score 0):

List all concurrent conditions using `OR MySQL Statement`:

`"SELECT * FROM PLACE.country WHERE Number='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."' OR StreetNumber='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."' OR PostNumber='" .mysql_real_escape_string($num) ."'";`

Comment: nice.  one answer for `AND` & one for `OR` :P

Comment: It is not obvious what  OP really wants :) I see I and three more people decided he wants an "OR" and you probably figured he wants "AND" because he said that he want to "JOIN" this statements :)